# Java GUI: JOptionPane.showInputDialog appearance changed

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a JOptionPane.showInputDialog box in Java. It works. When I call this code from inside the constructor, the box is fine. When I call this code from the main() method of the same class, the box's appearance is not the same. It still works, but its looks a bit basic. I would prefer to call the code from main() because it gives me greater flexibility. How can I get the look back to that of the first option?

```
String input1 = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
        (Object) ("Enter the size of the grid (an even integer > 8)"),
        "Grid size selection", 3, null, null, 12);

try {
    if (input1 == null)
        input1 = "12";
    num = Integer.parseInt(input1);
    if (num < 8)
        num = 8;
    else if (num % 2 == 1 && num > 8)
        num += 1;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're seeing two different look and feels. So where do you set the look and feel of the application? And is this a NetBeans application as NetBeans sometimes does this for you?

Comment: See [How to set the look and feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Comment: In your main method, add this line before any other: `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());`

Comment: No, I am working in Eclipse. But thank you all for the advice and for helping me to better understand Java's GUI functionality. I followed MadProgrammer's link and used the second try-catch option within the main method - as suggested by Guillaume Polet. It works!